# unexpected results of a left join

Tags: sql, left-join, sap-iq

I have a table named **test_table_1** and a view named **temp_test_view_1**.

The goal is to find the NEW_CATEGORY_ID for every ID in the test_table_1. The relationship between NEW_CATEGORY_ID and ID is in the view **temp_test_view_1**

I use the left join for that purpose, with the base table being test_table_1.

In my opinion, the left join returns some unexpected results.

Here is all the data contained in table **test_table_1**:

```
select * from test_table_1: 

id   name
1    'a'
null 'd'
3    'd'
2    'c'
2    'b'
```

Here is the view script:

```
create view temp_test_view_1 as
select
id,
id_description,
case when id_category = 'phone_id' then 'phone' else 'other' end as new_id_category
from (

select
1 as id,
'first id' as id_description,
null as id_category
from dummy

union all

select
2 as id,
'second id' as id_description,
'phone_id' as id_category
from dummy
) x
;
```

Here is the query I use to left join the view to a table and then project the results to see the corresponding new_id_category for every ID in test_table_1:

```
select
t1.id,
t1.name,
t2.id,
t2.id_description,
t2.new_id_category
from test_table_1 t1
left join temp_test_view_1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

output is:

```
id   name,id   id_description new_id_category  
null 'd'  null null,          'other'          
1    'a'  1   'first id'      'other'          
2    'b'  2   'second id'     'phone'          
2    'c'  2   'second id'     'phone'         
3    'd'  null null           'other'
```

desired output:

```
id   name,id   id_description new_id_category  
null 'd'  null null,          null          
1    'a'  1   'first id'      'other'          
2    'b'  2   'second id'     'phone'          
2    'c'  2   'second id'     'phone'        
3    'd'  null null           null
```

Can someone explain whether the result the query produces is correct and why if so? I expect this left join to return null on the columns retrieved from the view, as u can see from my desired outcome.

I did not test the query in DB systems offered by other vendors.

EDIT:
I tested it on sqlfiddle MS SQL, and it produces the desired output. Here is the link:
sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c788/2

If someone needs the code itself to reproduce the results in MS SQL, (while he will fail to reproduce the resulst and instead get the desired result):

```
create view temp_test_view_1 as
select
id,
id_description,
case when id_category = 'phone_id' then 'phone' else 'other' end as new_id_category
from (

select
1 as id,
'first id' as id_description,
null as id_category

union all

select
2 as id,
'second id' as id_description,
'phone_id' as id_category

) x
;


select *

into test_table_1

from (

select

1 as id,

'a' as name


union all

select

2 as id,

'b' as name


union all

select

2 as id,

'c' as name


union all

select

3 as id,

'd' as name


union all

select

null as id,

'd' as name


) x;
select
t1.id,
t1.name,
t2.id,
t2.id_description,
t2.new_id_category
from test_table_1 t1
left join temp_test_view_1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results as *text tables* are more readable.  An explanation of your problem is needed.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why do you expect that value? PS The where requires t1.id to be null, so why do you expect a t3.id to be equal to t1.id, ie null? PS Don't just give wrong code, find the first subexpression that doesn't return what you expect. And say why.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the output and desired output. I am trying to find the category id for every id in the main table.

Comment: You still don't say why you expect what you expect & I told you in my first comment why you get null for the subselect. Except now you have changed your code. Also you don't clearly say what the query is supposed to do, ie how the result is a function of input, you just give an example for us to guess from. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks for your reply. Those are just test tables/views to demonstrate the issue, no business relationships are involved. The query is supposed to show to which new_id_category the id's from t1 belong. The link between new_id_category and id is in the t2 view.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS A table represents a business relation(ship)/association. As in "relational model" & "entity-relationship model". FKs are wrongly called "relationships". PS You still haven't clearly said what the query is supposed to return. Or given code we can cut & paste & run.

Comment: case when id_category = 'phone_id' then 'phone' else 'other' end as new_id_category  if the id_category is null, the case statement fails and 'other' is returned.

Comment: @Sparky, is that the way left join works with subqueries or views? It returns the values of the column for the rows which are not even matched in a join?

Comment: @Sparky But regardless of what the view returns, when the left join has t1.id null that row is unmatched in a corresponding inner join so it is null-extended & added to the the inner join result to get the left join result. PS Too bad there's not a [mre] we can cut & paste & run to show that that code with that input should give the desired output in an SQL DBMS & so the asker can cut & paste & run on their DBMS to show what their output definitely was.

Comment: Yet again: Put everything needed into the post. Not just at a link. And don't put the link or something about the link in comments, put it into the post. Yes I know it gives your output at SQL Server, I just said it would. PS So you seem to have found a compiler bug, I didn't see any mention of it yet from a bit of googling. And since you ran MRE code at another DBMS, which you could & should have done before asking, you know you seem to have found a compiler bug. Check the product bug reports.

Comment: @philipxy, I edited the original post and added the script. Well, I appreciate your efforts to guide me, thanks.

Comment: Good luck. PS Can you clean up that code?  Eg only duplicate code that is  necessary for different DBMSs (like, your initializations), format initializations as tables, don't have extra blank lines, give initialization code for all tables, etc. PS Standard SQL allows VALUES in UPDATE & may be a portable initialization.

Comment: This open bug fits your description (but was reported against Solaris!) CR Number:    668751
Status:    Open
Description
The issue occurs whenever a null-generating side of an outer join is a

flattenable view [...] and the select list of the

view contains a constant expression [...]
Workaround Description
 WA would be to add a DISTINCT to the derived table. or move the constant to the upper select list and use an ISNULL check to add the constant info http://www.dbainfo.net/wp-content/uploads/CR/iq_15.htm#CR668751 via http://www.dbainfo.net/sap-iq-cr-number.htm via google.